# Loading a product collection through multiple stores

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, flat-catalog

We've created an additional indexer that is started by using the backend indexer functions. We have flat tables enabled. We have multiple storeviews that correspond to different languages.

The following code is an excerpt from the indexer code.

```
public function rebuildIndex ($productIds) {
  $stores = Mage::app()->getStores();
  foreach ($stores AS $store) {
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store);
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
      ->getCollection()
      ->setStore($store)
      ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
      ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array ('in' => array (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)))
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
      ->setPageSize(1000)
      ->setCurPage(++$page);
  }
}
```

The problem is that for the second and third store, the products loaded use the language of the first storeview.

We've tried finding out what the problem is. So far, we've seen that when using flat tables, the product flat tables created are these:

- catalog_product_flat_1
- catalog_product_flat_2
- catalog_product_flat_3

The number at the end corresponds to the storeview (and therefor the language). However, in all cases, the generated SELECT statement selects from the first table, making the language of the products loaded in all 3 storeviews the language of the first storeview.

We can't disable flat tables (which we tried, and that fixes the problem). Is there any way to load the products for each of the storeviews?

Comment: Try adding `addStoreFilter()` to your product collection after you set the store. I've not seen `setStore($store)` used before, but I have seen `setStoreId($store->getId())` - Not sure if there's gonna be a difference.

Comment: Added setStoreId(...) followed by addStoreFilter() to the building of the collection. No change.

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE were you able to solve this problem? If so, how?

Comment: We determined it to be a problem of the flat tables. We inserted a `Mage::unregister('_resource_singleton/catalog/product_flat');` right before doing the collection gathering, so the indexing would work around the flat tables. It's usually executed from the command line anyway, so performance wasn't critical.

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE, thanks, this solution works fine

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the same issue.

`Mage::unregister('_resource_singleton/catalog/product_flat');` didn't do the job for me.

I was able to solve it by setting the current context to `Admin` using:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
```

When you look into `_construct` method inside `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php`

You can see that it's initializing `catalog/product_flat` only when `isEnabledFlat` returns `true`.

And `isEnabledFlat` would return `false` when we are in the admin context